# Cannot call callback of the pushbutton of the uicontrol in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, callback, uicontrol

I am trying to create a button in GUI matlab and call a function when it is pressed. This code it is not working. I have also tried to use these values in the last argument of uicontrol:
fnHi, 'fnHi', 'fnHi();'

The code is:

```
function [] = testui()
    function fnHi()
         fprintf('hi');
    end
    fnHiHandler = @fnHi;
    fnHiHandler(); fnHi();
    figure();
    uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'string', 'Hi', 'callback', fnHiHandler);
end
```

The output is:

```
testui()
hihiUndefined function or variable 'fnHiHandler'.

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

So the function works since it is called twice but when I press the button it crashes.
I dont want to use more than one file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer. The problem is that fnHi should receive two arguments, otherwise it will crash saying that are too many input arguments. So this code works:

```
function [] = testui()
    function fnHi(source,eventdata)
         fprintf('hi');
    end
    fnHiHandler = @fnHi;
    fnHiHandler(); fnHi();
    figure();
    uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', 'string', 'Hi', 'callback', fnHiHandler);
end
```